# Как ускорить вычисления вероятностей на python

Tags: python, scipy

Есть код, считает правильно, но долго - около 10 сек. Можно ли как-то ускорить вычисления?

```
import scipy.stats as sps
mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ = 50, 50, 10, 10, 150
def find_prob(mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ):
    prob = 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(0, 301):
        for j in range(0, 301):
            if i + j < summ:
                prob = prob + (sps.norm(loc=mo1, scale=sig_h).cdf(i + 0.5) - sps.norm(loc=mo1, scale=sig_h).cdf(i - 0.5))*(sps.norm(loc=mo2, scale=sig_a).cdf(j + 0.5) - sps.norm(loc=mo2, scale=sig_a).cdf(j - 0.5))
    end = time.time()
    print('время: ' + str(end - start))
    
    return prob
```

Comment: Что вы считаете?

Comment: Можно. Сделать summ не 150, а 40, например.

Comment: в этой функции считается вероятность того, что сумма двух дискретных нормальных случайных величин будет меньше summ. у меня данные на самом деле целочисленные, распределены по нормальному закону, но я не нашел формул нахождения вер-тей для дискретных нормальных величин, поэтому так пытаюсь применить формулы для непрерывныхвеличин)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё вынести из циклов:

```
import scipy.stats as sps
import time


def find_prob(mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ):
    n1 = sps.norm(loc=mo1, scale=sig_h)
    n2 = sps.norm(loc=mo2, scale=sig_a)
    prob = 0
    start = time.time()
    a = [n1.cdf(i + 0.5) - n1.cdf(i - 0.5) for i in range(summ)]
    b = [n2.cdf(j + 0.5) - n2.cdf(j - 0.5) for j in range(summ)]
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        for j, bj in enumerate(b):
            if i + j < summ:
                prob = prob + ai * bj
    end = time.time()
    print('время: ' + str(end - start))
    
    return prob


# mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ = 50, 50, 10, 10, 150
print(find_prob(50, 50, 10, 10, 150))
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> время: 0.07240009307861328
> 0.9997664485607246
> ```

Сократить О-большое с квадрата до линии и перевести все вычисления на NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import time


def find_prob(mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ):
    prob = 0
    start = time.time()
    x = np.arange(summ + 1)
    a = np.diff(sps.norm(loc=mo1, scale=sig_h).cdf(x - 0.5))
    b = sps.norm(loc=mo2, scale=sig_a).cdf(x - 0.5)
    b -= b[0]
    b = b[1:]
    prob = np.dot(a, b[::-1])
    end = time.time()
    print('время: ' + str(end - start))
    return prob


# mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ = 50, 50, 10, 10, 150
print(find_prob(50, 50, 10, 10, 150))
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> время: 0.0018396377563476562
> 0.9997664485607203
> ```

Код ускорен примерно в восемнадцать тысяч раз. Тут и О-большое и константа.

Comment: спасибо, так гораздо лучше

Comment: О, вот второе решение - вообще отлично, конечно. Но это нужно было чётко разобраться, что тут происходит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, там несколько шагов, но идея не сложная: ТС переможает два набора конечных разностей. Конечные разности одной переменной (*a*) так и остаются. Конечные разности второй (*b*) накопительно суммируются. Внутренний цикл превращается в одно умножение (одна конечная разность *a* на сумму конечных разностей *b*).

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант с `lru_cache`, плюс `break` для досрочного выхода из цикла. Для чистоты эксперимента кэш чистится.

```py
import scipy.stats as sps
import time
from functools import lru_cache

mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ = 50, 50, 10, 10, 150

s1 = sps.norm(loc=mo1, scale=sig_h)
s2 = sps.norm(loc=mo2, scale=sig_a)

@lru_cache(None)
def cdf1(i):
    return s1.cdf(i)

@lru_cache(None)
def cdf2(i):
    return s2.cdf(i)

def find_prob(mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ):
    prob = 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(summ):
        for j in range(summ):
            if i + j < summ:
                prob = prob + (cdf1(i + 0.5) - cdf1(i - 0.5)) * (cdf2(j + 0.5) - cdf2(j - 0.5))
            else:
                break
    end = time.time()
    print('время: ' + str(end - start))
    
    return prob

cdf1.cache_clear()
cdf2.cache_clear()
print(find_prob(mo1, mo2, sig_h, sig_a, summ))
# время: 0.048853158950805664
# 0.9997664485607246
```